# $f(x) = -2x^2 + 10x - 8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For $f(x) = -2x^2 + 10x - 8$, labeling any intercepts and the vertex and showing the axis of symmetry.

I came up with $(0, -8)$, $(4, 0)$, $(1, 0)$, and the vertex $(2.5, 4.5)$. The axis of symmetry is then $x = 2.5$.

**My question is:**

How does one come up with $(1, 0)$ from $\frac{-10}{2(-2)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{-10}{2(-2)}$ or $\frac{-b}{2a}$ is the x-coordinate of the vertex, not the x intercept (which is what (1,0) is). x intercepts are found from solving $f(x)=0$

Comment: So how did one come up with that?

Comment: Come up with the $\frac{-b}{2a}$, or how to find the x-intercept?

Comment: I listed all the answers up above but the only one I'm having trouble with is the $(1, 0)$

Comment: If $(1,0)$ is on the graph, this is saying that when you input 1, the output is 0, that is $f(1)=0$. So finding x-intercepts, in general, is asking when does $f(x)=0$. To solve $f(x)=0$, there are a few ways, but the one that works the most often is the quadratic formula.

Comment: Ok that gives me $(1, 4)$.

Comment: Close, it is giving you $x=4$ OR $x=1$, but for either of these, $f$ takes the value zero, so they correspond to $(1,0)$ and $(4,0)$

Comment: $y=f(x)$. So when you solve $f(x)=0$ you are finding what $x$ values make $y$ equal 0.